# SQL Query Effeciency - Using Left Outer Joins VS Nested Select statement

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables, defined as (Assume ID fields are Primary Keys / Unique):

```
create table TestTable (ID int, Z1 int, Z2 int, Z3 int)

create table ZDetails(zID int, zName varchar(255))
```

With the following data:

[image]

[image]

Now, in the `TestTable`, the columns `Z1`, `Z2`, `Z3` correspond to `zID` in `ZDetails`.

What I want to do is to display data in `TestTable` along with the `zName`s fetched from `ZDetails`.

I see two ways of doing this:

1. With a Nested Select:

```
SELECT ID,
        Z1,
        ZN1 = (SELECT zName FROM ZDetails WHERE zID = Z1),
        Z2,
        ZN2 = (SELECT zName FROM ZDetails WHERE zID = Z2)
FROM TestTable
```

2. With a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT ID,
    Z1,
    ZD1.zName,
    Z2,
    ZD2.zName
FROM TestTable
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ZDetails ZD1 on Z1 = ZD1.zID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ZDetails ZD2 on Z2 = ZD2.zID
```

I find the first one simpler to read but the Estimated Execution Plan looks complex compared to the second one.

Which one do you think would be more efficent? Also, is there a better way to do this? (Without modifying the tables schema)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you have multiple tables in a query, you should always use qualified column names.  For the first query, that would be:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Z1,
        ZN1 = (SELECT z.zName FROM ZDetails z WHERE z.zID = t.Z1),
        t.Z2,
        ZN2 = (SELECT z.zName FROM ZDetails z WHERE z.zID = t.Z2)
FROM TestTable t;
```

And similarly for the second query.

Which is better?  They do different things.  The second can return multiple rows if there are multiple matches in `ZDetails`.  The correlated subqueries would return an error in this case.

In general, you seem to be doing lookups in a reference table.  That is more commonly done using a `JOIN`.  But with the right indexes on the tables (which primary keys provide) there is probably little performance difference between the two.

However, the execution plans are different because the code is doing different things (with respect to duplicates).

Comment: Given the fact that ID fields are Primary Keys, they do exactly the same. Execution plans would be the same in ideal case. They may differ as optimal plan is not guaranteed, but it is not because they do different things in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient way is to use the join method instead of the nested select method.
When you use the nested query, you are executing the nested query one by one than executing the parent query while in the query using the join method you will be executing a query once.

I attached a image of the difference of join methods that can be used and that are very useful to know.[image]

Comment: Trust the dbms optimizer - depending on the dbms used...